# React Textarea with state can't be update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-component

I am working on a ReactJs app. Here I have a `Textarea` which is connected to a `state`

```
<Textarea className="c-input" tabIndex="7" minRows={4}
    ref="adMessage"
    onKeyPress={ console.log('keypress textarea') }
    onChange={ console.log('changed text area') }
    placeholder=""
    value={this.state.adDescription}
/>
```

In another controller, I've some tag's and on click of them, I can update the `adDescription` state like this

```
handelSetDescription = (label) => {

        let message = '';

        if (this.state.adDescription.length === 0){

            message = this.state.adDescription + label;

        } else if (this.state.adDescription.length > 0){

            message = this.state.adDescription + ", " + label;
        }

        this.setState({
            adDescription: message
        });

    };
```

But I want to manually add more text to the Textarea as well, but seems I can't add any text there. When I click on the Textarea and type something, it just dont do anything.

[image]

How can I add text there manually?

Comment: Your `onChange` attribute doesn't actually do anything. If you need a controlled input you need to define that. Otherwise, if you want an uncontrolled component (not recommended) change `value` to `defaultValue`.

Comment: Following on from @Chris's comment, [React documentation for forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) is a good read.

Comment: @wing This article and few other linked article helped to understand Controlled vs Uncontrolled components. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like this according to your business logic.

```
<Textarea className="c-input" tabIndex="7" minRows={4}
ref="adMessage"
onKeyPress={ console.log('keypress textarea') }
onChange={ this.someFunctionName }
placeholder=""
value={this.state.adDescription}
```

/>

Function can do something like following:

```
changeStateForDescription = (val) => {
   this.setState({
        adDescription: val
    });
}

handelSetDescription = (label) => {

    let message = '';

    if (this.state.adDescription.length === 0){

        message = this.state.adDescription + label;

    } else if (this.state.adDescription.length > 0){

        message = this.state.adDescription + ", " + label;
    }

    this.changeStateForDescription(message);

};

someFunctionName = (e) => {
 this.changeStateForDescription(this.state.adDescription + e.target.value);
}
```